# Only show relevant intellisense suggestions in VSCode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

This problem is difficult to explain.
In the image below, how do I get VSCode to only show `adjL`? I only want suggestions from the file I'm currently editing.

[image: limitSuggestions]

Currently, it shows a whole list of variables that I don't ever use.

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Adding this to your setting.json should do it.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": false,
    "variable": true
}
```

But I not recomended that, because intellisence is realy helpfull! ;)

Unless you only care about hiding other variables but not other types of prompts.

Comment: But after this, `adjL` is not shown either.

Comment: Maybe adjL is a field not local variable, I dont kniw that from pice of code, so try also: "field": true

Comment: Or other order of elements in json

Comment: It is a local variable. Strangely, it only shows up when `other` is turned on. But that turns on everything else too. Same for the `colored` variable that you see in the image.
I turned on almost everything except `other`. No luck.
I'm using `1.52.1`
Is it working for you?